# KendoUI Datasource won't transmit data to ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, kendo-ui

I have the Problem, that the Datasource i created doesn't get any data. If i visit the url manually it obviously is there. I can't find out where I go wrong. Help is appreciated. I created a JSbin to illustrate the problem.http://jsbin.com/unEPAwAn/4/edit
The Code:

```
var eventsViewModel = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport:{
read: {
url:"https://myurl/incidents",
        datatype: "jsonp"
    }
},
schema:{
data:function(response){
console.log(response);
return response;}
},
sort:{field: "id", dir: "desc"}
});

var events = eventsViewModel.fetch(function(){
var data = this.data();
console.log(data.length);
console.log(data[0]);
});

$("#eventsList").kendoListView({
dataSource: eventsViewModel,
template: kendo.template($("#eventsTemplate").html())
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. The document that you are receiving from the URL is a JSON and not a JSONP.
2. If you change the dataType to JSON (instead of JSONP) then JSBin cannot work because you are pulling data from a different domain which is not allowed because Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

So either you have your server serving a JSONP document or you change `dataType` to JSON and serve the document from the same URL than the HTML document.

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot this makes things a bit clearer. Although I don't know where i know about the domain I'm working in(apart from JSbin) since I'm developing a mobile App.